# Get values of 2 or more keys of input request json in a single validation rules callback function

Tags: codeigniter

Following is the code of my

> application/config/form_validation.php file

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config = array(
    'signup' => array(
            array(
                    'field' => 'first_name',
                    'label' => 'first_name',
                    'rules' => 'required|callback_fullname_chk'                    
            ),
            array(
                'field' => 'last_name',
                'label' => 'last_name',
                'rules' => 'required'                    
        )
));
```

Following is the code of my

> application/controllers/UserController.php

```
public function reg_form()
    {
        $input_data_array = (array)json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

        $this->form_validation->set_data($input_data_array);
        if ($this->form_validation->run('signup') == FALSE)
        {                   
                $result = array('status' => 404,'message' => $this->form_validation->error_array());
                $this->output->set_output(json_encode($result));
        }
        else
        {
                $result = array('status' => 200,'message' => 'Executed Succesfully','data'=>$input_data_array);
                $this->output->set_output(json_encode($result));
        }
    }



public function fullname_chk($str)
 {
         if ($str == 'admin')
         {
                 $this->form_validation->set_message('fullname_chk', 'The {field} field can not be the word "admin"');
                 return FALSE;
         }
         else
         {
                 return TRUE;
         }
 }
```

In the 'fullname_chk' callback function I get the value of the first_name implicitly in $str variable, which I can use for my custom validation. My requirement is to get even the value of the last_name (Second input json key) inside the same callback, together with first_name, maybe as a second parameter, as I wan't to write a business logic to check the uniqueness of first_name and last_name taken together. Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `fullname_chk` function you can access any post/get variables as you normally would. In this case you can reuse `$input_data_array = (array)json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));` however there isn't another way to pass extra data to the callback unless you want to do some sort of validation outside the form validation library.

Comment: Thank You for the valuable input. It worked for me by reusing $input_data_array ... but it is like a tightly coupled solution, in which I need to modify the callback function for using it for different tables with different column names and can't reuse in general. Do you have any solution for making it a reusable callback?

Comment: Not really. Pradeep addressed the other way of possibly doing it. TBH I wouldn't be too worried about how tightly coupled things are as codeigniter code tends to be rather tightly coupled compared to other frameworks.

Comment: But even in Pradeep's solution, I am not getting how do I catch hold of the last_name key data and pass as the parameter. Can you help me doing it?

Comment: Great Solutions. Thank You.